# Найти разницу во времени между просмотрами экранных форм

Tags: sql

Как посчитать разницу между полями дат sa_add_date и nextTimeAction по каждому sa_dp? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный запрос:

```
select sa_cid
        , sa_add_date
        , sa_t
        , sa_cd8
        , sa_cd9
        , sa_dp
        , lead(sa_dp) over(partition by sa_cid order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9) as next_sadp
        , lead(sa_add_date) over(partition by sa_cid order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9) as timeNextAction
        , row_number() over(partition by sa_cid, sa_cd8 order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9, rowkey) rowNumber
    from RU_SVC_QW_ANALITICS.SITE_ACTIVITY_KR
    where true 
        and sa_add_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 2
        and sa_add_date < trunc(sysdate)
        and sa_cid = '486276991.1566834919'
```

Comment: `select t1.sa_dp, datediff(second,min(t1.sa_add_date),max(t2.timeNextAction) ) from table t1 join  table t2 on t1.sa_db = t2.sa_db ...`

Comment: Задачу решил так:

Answer (score 1):

Задачу решил так:

```
select *
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, mintime, maxtime) as diff 
from (
select sa_cid
        , sa_add_date
        , sa_t
        , sa_cd8
        , sa_cd9
        , sa_dp
        , min(sa_add_date) over(partition by sa_cid, sa_dp order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9) as mintime
        , lead(sa_dp) over(partition by sa_cid order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9) as next_sadp
        , max(sa_add_date) over(partition by sa_cid, sa_dp order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9) as maxtime
        , row_number() over(partition by sa_cid, sa_cd8 order by sa_add_date, sa_cd8, sa_cd9, rowkey) rowNumber
    from RU_SVC_QW_ANALITICS.SITE_ACTIVITY_KR
    where true 
        and sa_add_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 2
        and sa_add_date < trunc(sysdate)
        and sa_cid = '486276991.1566834919' ) as t1
where sa_dp <> next_sadp
```